# Oracle 12c sys.snap$ view does not exist

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run Redgate Schema compare tool, and I am getting the following errors:

```
SELECT s.sowner as owner, s.vname as mview_name, decode(bitand(s.flag, 262144), 262144, 'Y', 'N') as reduced_precisions 
FROM sys.snap$ s 
WHERE (s.sowner = 'OBSOLESCENCE_DATA_STORE' );
10:25:26.511|Error  |Object Model        |7  |Failed to execute reader
Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
at Devart.Data.Oracle.a7.b(Int32 A_0)
at Devart.Data.Oracle.a9.a(Int32 A_0, bw A_1)
at Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand.InternalExecute(CommandBehavior behavior, IDisposable disposable, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, Boolean nonQuery)
at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean nonQuery)
at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
at RedGate.Oracle.Common.ObjectModel.DatabaseReader.ExecuteReader(String script)
```

I tried to query the view directly from sql developer, but with no luck.  I'm assuming this isn't correct, but I have no idea how to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What user are you running this as? Are you 100% sure you have access to that view?

Comment: I'm not a dba, I'm a developer, so I don't really know how to check.  How would I go about finding that out?

Comment: Ask your DBA. You aren't going to have access to all of the internal sys views by default.

Comment: We don't have a DBA per se, but I asked the guy who is the closest.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked sometime back. For all others benifit I would like to respond.

As per my knowledge these type of views can be accessed by **sys** user by default. 
Since the user doesn't have a DBA and if he is aware of how to logon as "**sys as sysdba**" then you should be able to access **snap$**.

The alternate method is to ask the DBA to grant

```
GRANT SELECT on sys.snap$ to *[user logged in]*
```